# PHP sprintf usage issue

Tags: php, printf

I've faced an  php `sprintf` string in *PHP Objects, patterns and practice* book :

```
    $txtout = "";
    $pad = 4*$num;
    $txtout .= sprintf( "%{$pad}s", "" );
```

I'm not sure, but i think the author is aimed to build padding(indent) based on `$pad` , but actually it doesn't work, is this code syntactically right?

Comment: does seem like nonsense - far easier with str_repeat perhaps. I assume that there is a number assigned to `$num`? It is adding the spaces though

Comment: @RamRaider yes `$num` is an integer , fetching from another part of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it does work to add spaces or padding - it's just that in plain html generally you will not see the spaces/padding - though inside a `pre` tag it will become apparent.

```
$num=10;
$txtout = "";
$pad = 4*$num;
$txtout .= sprintf( "%{$pad}s", "" );

/* you should see the word hello spaced out across the page */
echo '<pre>',print_r( $txtout.'hello'.$txtout.'hello',true ),'</pre>';
```

Comment: thanks, it does work, but what is the necessitate of changing `print_r` second parameter to `true`?

Comment: the use of `true` as the 2nd parameter means that `print_r` returns the value rather than printing it to screen.. could have done the same thing with a basic `echo` statement but that is just how my test was setup.

Comment: yes, i know that, but i have never seen using `,` to concatenate strings,as i have always used `.` is it eligible to use `,` instead of `.` to connect multiple strings?

Comment: yep - you can string things together like that in an echo statement